# How to use class function variable within a local function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress shortcode plugin, so I need to define a function to use with `add_action('wp_footer', 'fnc_name')` for example.  I have created the plugin as a class with public functions and static variables.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do (use `$count` in the local function `tryToGetIt`):

```
class Test {

    public static $count;

    public function now () {
        if (!$this::$count) {
            $this::$count = 0;
        }
        $this::$count++;

        $count = (string) $this::$count;

        echo 'count should be '.$count;

        function tryToGetIt() {
            global $count;
            echo 'count is '.$count;
        }
        tryToGetIt();
    }
};

$test = new Test();
$test->now();
```

You can see the demo on IDEONE: http://ideone.com/JMGIFr

The output is 'count should be 1 count is ';

As you can see I've tried declaring the `$count` variable with `global` to use the variable from the outer function, but that is not working.  I've also tried `$self = clone $this` and using `global $self` within the local function.

How can the local function use the variables from within the class's public function?

Comment: I wonder why you're considering using a "nested" function, it's not obvious what you gain from it.

Comment: Trying to define a function to use with WordPress's `add_action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code, which works

```
class Test {

    public static $count;

    public function now () {
        if (!$this::$count) {
            $this::$count = 0;
        }
        $this::$count++;

        $count = (string) $this::$count;

        echo 'count should be '.$count;

        function tryToGetIt() {
            echo 'count is '. Test::$count;
        }
        tryToGetIt();
    }
};

$test = new Test();
$test->now();
```

But I'm not sure I understand why you are trying to do this. Why not make tryToGetIt() a private function within Test rather than nested within now()?

Comment: Is that proper though?  Shouldn't you use the class instance instead of the class itself?

Comment: I've built a test case, and it seems to work fine if I make sure to check if the function exists already: http://ideone.com/tdpnnZ

Comment: With a static variable, accessing it via the instance should be functionally equivalent to accessing it via the class itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with `global`. PHP has exactly two variable scopes: global, and local.

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar'; // global scope  <-----------
                                           \
function x() {                             |
    $foo = 'baz'; // function local scope  |
                                           |
    function y() {                         |  
       global $foo; // access global scope /
       echo $foo;
    }
    y();
}

x(); // outputs 'bar'
```

You COULD try a closure, e.g.

```
function foo() {
   $foo = 'bar';
   $baz = function() use (&$foo) { ... } 
}
```

There is no practical way to access a scope defined at some intermediate level of a function call chain. You only ever have the local/current scope, and the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
function tryToGetIt($count) {
        echo 'count is '.$count;
    }
    tryToGetIt($count);
```

Or to select the static variable use:

`Test::$count` within the tryToGetIt() function.

Comment: I would, but since I need to pass a function name (with no arguments) to WordPress, I don't think I can.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-arguments-to-add_action Does this help?